# Best way to cross-fade ImageViews

Tags: android, cross-fade

I am working on this project for my class.
You can click an image of Bart Simpson and it fades out while Homer Simpson fades in.

What I need help with is to make it possible to click Homer and return to Bart.

My code is

Activity_xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.eric.layoutdemo2.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bart"
        android:onClick="fade"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/homer"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bart"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:src="@drawable/homer"
       />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;


   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

       public void fade(View view) {

        ImageView bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);

        ImageView homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homer);


        bart.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

        homer.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        bart.bringToFront();
    }

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }




    }
```

Comment: basically: keep track of what's being shown, so you know which picture you need to fade to.

Comment: What I need is to be able to click on homer and go back to bart but I dont know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, you have to define an OnClickListener to homer object and when it triggered call fade function.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView homer, bart;

    private void fade(ImageView v1, ImageView v2) {
        v1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        v2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        v2.bringToFront();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);
        homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homer);

        bart.setOnClickListener(this);
        homer.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bart:
                fade(bart, homer);
                     break;

            case R.id.homer:
                fade(homer, bart);
                     break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please click the tick meaning solution is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Following is a easy way to perform cross-fading and return with another click:

## The XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="fade"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bart"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="105dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="190dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/homer"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="105dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="190dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## The Main :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void fade(View view){
        ImageView bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);
        ImageView homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homer);
        if (bart.getAlpha()==1f) {
            bart.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(4000);
            homer.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(4000);
        }
        else{
            bart.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(4000);
            homer.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(4000);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much easier way. Just add an onclick function on homer and use `.bringToFront();` to bring him infront of bart, this is because although homer is visible and bart is not bart is infront of him and the second function will not get executed similarly. Use `.bringToFront();` on bart. I have used other images.
Here is the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pembatamang.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/eevee"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="fade1"
        android:src="@drawable/evee"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/squirtle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:onClick="fade"
        android:src="@drawable/squirtle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is the java code.

```
package com.example.pembatamang.myapplication;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void fade(View view) {
        ImageView squirtle1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.squirtle);
        ImageView eevee1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eevee);
        squirtle1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        eevee1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        eevee1.bringToFront();
    }

    public void fade1(View view) {
        ImageView squirtle1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.squirtle);
        ImageView eevee1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eevee);
        eevee1.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        squirtle1.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        squirtle1.bringToFront();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add the ImageView of bart and homer in the XML file and set their id as bart and homer respectively.

Then set the alpha value of bart to 1 and alpha of homer to 0 in the same design menu of the XML file.

After that add this code in the java file of the activity.

```
public void fade(View view)
{
    ImageView bart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bart);
    ImageView homer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homer);

    bart.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
    homer.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
}
```